# how does this .join(this) work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say in this context:

```
String.prototype.times = function(count) {
    return count < 1 ? '' : new Array(count + 1).join(this);
}

"hello!".times(3); //"hello!hello!hello!";
"please...".times(6); //"please...please...please...please...please...please..."
```

How does it add on to the new statement 3 times? I'm also having some confusion in understanding the return statement. Please tell me if I am understanding this correctly:

```
(if count < 1){
    return ''
} else {
    return new Array(count + 1).join(this) //This I don't understand.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes a new array of given length, say 7. Then you join all those empty items with a string, which ends up repeating that string 6 times.

Normally:

```
[1,2,3].join("|") === "1|2|3"
```

Then with an array of length 4:

```
new Array(4).join("|") === "|||"
```

`this` inside a `String.prototype` method refers to the string object the function was called as a method on:

```
 "hello".bold(); //this would refer to a string object containing "hello" inside bold()
```

Comment: Ah I see. But why does it have to have a given length of 7? Is the array attached to the original string since it is .join(this)?

Comment: @SeanDokko `7` was an example, you can pass any number as an argument there. If I said `.times(15)` then `count + 1` equals 16 which makes a `new Array(16)` which then joins 15 strings together. The array created is not attached to anything, it's created and lost.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the further clarification.

Answer (score 3):

`this`, in this context, refers to the string that is being affected. So if I call `"hello".times(5)`, then `this` will refer to `"hello"`.

The function works by creating an array with `count+1` elements, effectively making `count` "gaps" between them. Then the pieces are glued together with the `this` string, resulting it `this` repeated `count` times.

Of course, if it is being told to repeat less than once, the result is empty. The `count < 1` check is to avoid errors with invalid array sizes.

Answer (score 1):

`.join()` will join cells of array, resulting in a string. For example:

```
var arr = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ];

var str = arr.join(', ');

// str is now "one, two, three"
```

So, in your `times` function, you are saying `new Array(count + 1)`. So, if `count` is 3, you are actually making an *empty* array of 4 cells. You are then joining those *empty* cells with `this` (which is the string).

Answer (score 0):

This method creates a new array of the given length, plus 1. For example:

```
"hello".times(3);
```

Would create the following array:

```
[undefined × 4]
```

Each of these array elements are then joined together with `.join("hello")`. This basically translates out to this:

```
"" /* undefined array element */ + "hello" /* join string */ + "" + "hello" ...
```

---

And yes, you seem to be understanding the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(times) {
    return new Array(times+1).join(this);    
}

"go ".repeat(3) + "Giants!"; //"go go go Giants!"
```

The focus is on the separator argument while the base array comprises only undefined member values. Above example could be rewritten in longhand as:

```
[undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined].join("go ") + "Giants!";
```

With Join operator, each array member is converted into a string (in this case an empty string) before being concatenated.

Source: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/javascripts-dream-team-in-praise-of-split-and-join/